# Angularjs Directive content not linked to isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working with directives and my objective is to bind the value to my grandchild component and update the parent element, but this code doesn't bubble up to the root.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('root', function ($scope) {
  vm = this;
 vm.value = 'Joe Doe';
});

myApp.directive('child', function () {
 return {
   restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      paramOne: '=paramOne'
    },
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
      console.log('Child value: ', scope.paramOne);
    }
  }
});

myApp.directive('grandchild', function () {
 return {
   restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      paramTwo: '=paramTwo'
    },
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
      console.log('Grandchild value: ', scope.paramTwo);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="root as vm">
  Field Value: <strong>{{vm.value}}</strong>
  <hr>
  <div child param-one="vm.value">
    Child param value: {{paramOne}}    
    <div grandchild param-two="paramOne">
      Granchild param value: {{paramTwo}} <br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="paramTwo" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've made some research but didn't found any solution for this case.
I would appreciate any given help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directives need to transclude the contents and attach it to the element in the linking function:

```
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn(scope, function(clone) {
        elem.append(clone);
      });
```

## [The DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eyp61VnO8SD8qUez0GTH?p=preview)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('root', function ($scope) {
    vm = this;
    vm.value = 'Joe Doe';
});

myApp.directive('child', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      paramOne: '=paramOne'
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn(scope, function(clone) {
        elem.append(clone);
      });

      console.log('Child value: ', scope.paramOne);
    }
  }
});

myApp.directive('grandchild', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      paramTwo: '=paramTwo'
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn(scope, function(clone) {
        elem.append(clone);
      });

      console.log('Grandchild value: ', scope.paramTwo);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="root as vm">
  Field Value: <strong>{{vm.value}}</strong>
  <hr>
  <div child param-one="vm.value">
    Child param value: {{paramOne}}    
    <div grandchild param-two="paramOne">
      Granchild param value: {{paramTwo}} <br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="paramTwo" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg, is this transclude function always necessary? I made some test with one level bind (root to child) and it was working fine.. anyway, thanks again!

Comment: You are mistaken that one level bind worked just fine. If you set the binding name to something different than the attribute name, you will see that it is not working. Normally content inside an element binds to the parent scope. Directives such as `ng-if`, `ng-include`, `ng-repeat`, etc. transclude their contents.